# Using Spring Boot and Predicate with findAll: How to exclude orphan records from findAll and also avoid EntityNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am currently using the following objects:

Here is the parent entity:

```
@Table(name = "parent_table")
public class Parent {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int                      id;

    private String                   name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "parent")
    private Set<Child> children = null;

 }
```

Here is the child entity

```
@Table(name = "child_table")
public class Child {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int           id;

    private String        value;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id", nullable = false)
    private Parent parent;

}
```

Recently, someone with delete permissions did a hard delete of the parent record in the database table without deleting the child record in the child table.  This caused a 500 exception in the response.  (At this time, integrity rules are not being used at the database level).

While a person should never do a hard delete, this should not bring our system down.

Here is the simplified code that fails when the parent row is deleted from the Parent table but the child rows are not deleted:

```
private Predicate buildPredicate(Root<Child> root, CriteriaQuery<Child> query, CriteriaBuilder cb, String value) {
        List<Predicate> predicates = new ArrayList<>();

        predicates.add(cb.equal(root.get("value"), value));

        // ... additional predicate.add calls which I have removed for this example

        return cb.and(predicates.toArray(new Predicate[0]));
}

public List<Parent> getParents(String value) throws RedirectsServiceException {
    try {
        List<Child> children = childRepository.findAll((root, query, cb) -> buildPredicate(root, query, cb, value));
        return children.stream().map(Child::getParent).distinct().collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new MyException(e.getMessage() + " while executing getParents", e);
    }
}
```

Here is the error that I am seeing if someone deletes a row in the Parent table.

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.path.Parent with id 618 while executing getParents
```

Ideally, I would like to ignore the Child records that are missing the parent.  I would like to have no exception and include ONLY the Child records that have the value but are not missing a parent record.

Should I use exists?  Should I use a subquery?  What is a straight forward way to handle this?

Comment: Fix your database, you shouldn't be able to delete fk records.

Comment: I don't have control over the database which is shared with other teams.

Comment: Tell them to fix it, this isn't something you should even have to think about in your application.

Comment: I agree.  In this case Database Integrity rules would be the best practice. :-)

Comment: How to fix this? I face the same issue, the database table should be auto generated by that code right?

Comment: I did find a workaround using `fetch = FetchType.LAZY`.  The basic idea is that I can then catch the exception later.  This works out while we wait for the integrity rules to be added so that the workaround is not needed.  If it is interesting to anyone, let me know and I will post it as the answer.